# Tkinter grid can't place anywhere but dead center of screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

So I just need a photo for a background, and then a button in a certain spot.
I have the background image loading, but now when I try and place the button it will only go straight into the center of the screen. If I make the column or row anything other than 0, the button goes off the screen.

The full variable is just for if the user wants fullscreen or not, I don't want it to resize to any specific size, just full screen or half. But that's irrelevant.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

full= False
pilImage= Image.open("test.png")
width, height = pilImage.size
new_size = width/2, height/2
resized_image = pilImage.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)



root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)



if full:
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    canvas= Canvas(root, width=1920, height=1080)
    background= ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    change_window_size_button= Button(root, text="Switch to windowed.", command=root.quit)

else:
    root.geometry("960x540")
    canvas= Canvas(root, width=960, height=540)
    background= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    change_window_size_button= Button(root, text="Switch to fullscreen.", command=root.quit)

canvas.grid(row=0)
label= Label(canvas, image=background)
label.grid(row=0)

change_window_size_button.grid(row=0, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

![What it looks like]: https://ibb.co/cycTFT

EDIT:
Ok so I found out something new, the problem is that the canvas with the background image is made the default size for the cells.
So if i make it go past row and column 0, it goes off the screen into another cell.
Here's where the button goes if i make it row=0 and column=1.

![row=0 and column=1]: https://ibb.co/jWt2aT

So I need to make the cells small while maintaining the size of the image, meaning I need to somehow make that take up multiple cells. I still don't know how to do that... But progress none the less.

Comment: so that we can test it out, what is the size of the image that you are using?

Comment: @BryanOakley 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted specifically, but I was able to keep the button within the Tkinter window by adding

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

and then changing the grid location of the button like

```
change_window_size_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

this establishes a basis for which to place Widgets inside the "master grid" (root), if you will.

setting `row=0` places the button back into the center.

if you mess with this a little bit, you should be able to get the button where you want it.

[tkinter button below image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF3JR.jpg)

edit: explanation

Comment: So my goal is to make the button appear inside one of the three main big boxes, but towards the top, I just need to be able to move it with more control.

Comment: @Hayden I think a good lesson on `grid` would really help here; I would start [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm), it is a very simple example. You can use `columnspan` and `rowspan` as arguments inside `grid` to allow the widget to take up multiple columns and rows respectively.

Comment: Thank you, your completely right. I'm not the best at finding good sources to learn from, I appreciate you linking me the material! ^-^

Comment: @Hayden If Tkinter is your jam I can't say enough good things about [this dude](https://pythonprogramming.net/tkinter-depth-tutorial-making-actual-program/). OOP is the only way to make large Tkinter programs.

Comment: @Hayden if this answer helped could you select it as an accepted answer :) thank you